# Help appending html data from json encoded data

Tags: jquery, json, append

I am having trouble getting the html data from a json string to append properly after jquery post.

The problem I am having is that the slashes are not being removed from the html so the select list is not displaying and the html is outputting incorrectly. I have tried parsing the data after I

Here is the json string I have:

```
{"type":"success","list":"<li id=\"item-1><p>Test<\/p><p><select name=\"steps\">\n<option value=\"3\">Step 1<\/option>\n<option value=\"2\">Step 2<\/option>\n<option value=\"6\">Step 3<\/option>\n<option value=\"5\">Step 5<\/option>\n<\/select><\/p><\/li><li id=\"item-18><p>Testinggg<\/p><\/li>"}
```

And here is how it is created:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
        if (data)
        {
            if(data.type =='success') {
                jQuery("#item-list").append(data.list);
            }
        }
    },
    type: 'POST',
    data: {items: JSON.stringify(data)},
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "/action/create/" 
});
```

and in php:

```
$data = array(
    'type' => 'success',
    'list' => $list
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: What creates $list in your PHP code?

Comment: You're missing a closing `\"` in your data after item-1 and item-18.  This could be causing a parse error on appending to the DOM.  With those added in it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/RMnLG/

Comment: @mVChr  - Yes you are correct about the about missing the ". Can't believe I didn't spot that. Thank you

Comment: @mVChr: You should make that an answer so the OP can accept it

Comment: Done, just felt silly for something so... silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Nobody Panic, Just A Syntax Error

You're missing a closing `\"` in your data after item-1 and item-18. This is causing a parse error on appending to the DOM. With those added in it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/RMnLG